# define the area clickable to move a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay so I was wondering how to make it so that you can move a div using a child tag eg a image. http://jsfiddle.net/code_cookies/5e75N/

```
$(".drag").draggable({
containment: "#draggable"});
```

In the example I made you can move the box by clicking on it at any point and I was wondering if you could restrict so that you have to click the image to move the parent div?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried anything yet? done any research? looked at any documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, add `handle: "img"`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5e75N/1/)**

```
$(".drag").draggable({
    containment: "#draggable",
    handle: "img" 
});
```

See: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-handle

Comment: Works perfectly thank you i will be sure to double check the api next time.